# New web page and edited localhost/index.html gives a 404 error

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, lamp

I am using Ubuntu and have AMP.  I tried to create a new folder under /var/www/html/ it says not found.  I edited the http://localhost/index.html and that gives me a 404 error.  I guess its something to do with the security.

localhost/index.html was OK before the edit

Appreciate all assistance.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Can you describe _exactly_ what you did, and show the exact error messages you got? If you can copy and paste from your terminal session, that's usually best, as long as the excerpts are not too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logs are located in `/var/log/httpd/` error_log will provide you with a good starting point.

Maybe this is what your looking for:

`chcon -Rv -usystem_u -robject_r -thttpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html`

At least it will be able to rule that out as an issue. I'm guessing you do not have any relevant errors in your logs?

Comment: I think its more of a security issue, with selinux, any grabs on that?

Comment: Maybe this is what your looking for:

chcon -Rv -usystem_u -robject_r -thttpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html


http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html

At least it will beable to rule that out as an issue. 

I'm guessing you do not have any relevant errors in your logs?

Comment: @ash It worked, can put this as an answer, so I can vote. Thanks

Comment: @nife I cannot vote, I need a 15 reputation????

Comment: @Jean Glad to hear. Good Luck with your LAMP Setup.